# VBA stops with error code 1004 -> blanket value in slicer and in loop types incompatible

Tags: excel, vba

At first, I have to say, that my code worked for the last 4 months without any problem. But since this week it throws me an error during the loop of the slicer items. I have three times the same code but for three different countries. It still works for two of it. I don't know why not for the third one (how I said, the codes are identical).

I am thankful for any help!

```
s = Array("Jack", "Lisa", "John", "Jasson")
    j = 0
    For j = 0 To 3
    'MsgBox s(j)

    'Pivot-Filter wieder resetten
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Datenschnitt_KDName1").ClearManualFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Datenschnitt_Land").ClearManualFilter

    'Filter durchgehen
    With f
         For Each i In .PivotItems
           If i.Name <> s(j) Then
                i.Visible = False
           Else:
                i.Visible = True
           End If
         Next
    End With
```

[image: 123]
[image: 123]

[image: 123]

Comment: If it’s the last item, it’ll raise an error

Comment: Ok and how can I avoid it? Or can change the order of the items?

Comment: You can count the visible items against the totals and skip it if it’s the last one. You have to leave at least one visible. Either way, check it that’s what you're doing.

Comment: I don't get the problem. Why are the other two codes are working but this one not? The only difference is the content of the array. But they all compare the same .PivotItems

Comment: without seeing the actual data itsyjust a guess

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason for the error. I do not know why, but the last PivotItem changed the spelling from the source. Now it was different to the array item. For example:

Jasson changed to JASSON in PivotTable. I changed the array value now and it works again!